# Using 'Any' instead of specific HTTP verb in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

What are the advantages of using a specific HTTP verb instead of the 'Any' method in a ServiceStack.Service inherited implementation?

I understand you can change behaviour between the HTTP verbs if you want, but if you don't have this requirement is there any benefit of using a specific verb (i.e. GET/POST/PUT/DELETE).

Since we also you quite a lot of messages using MessagingService it seems to make sense to use Any, just to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Any()` is a preference on whether you want to Service available on any Verb or not, there's no real disadvantage to using it, but reasons you may not want to include:

1. You want to control/limit how Consumers use your Service and
2. Reduce conflicts when re-using the same route and distinguish calls by verb

My personal preference is to use `Any()` until I need to re-use the same route for different Services, at which point I'll switch to specific verbs.

Comment: As the lead of the project I assume you know there's not technical difference between those in terms of performance?

Comment: @Gabriël Essentially none, it's [literally an extra Dictionary lookup](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/824227c8e6c4ab5333ff19519dc45431191706e3/src/ServiceStack/Host/ServiceExec.cs#L170).